# Building CopperheadOS Android. Failed: mkbootfs.o

Tags: android

Building CopperheadOS for Pixel 2XL (taimen) I arrive to this issue:

`FAILED: out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/mkbootfs.o`

The complete log from terminal at executing `make target-files-package -j10` is:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.9.0-11-amd64-x86_64-Debian-GNU/Linux-9-(stretch)
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ3A.190801.002
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
ninja: no work to do.
ninja: no work to do.
No need to regenerate ninja file
No need to regenerate ninja file
[  0% 10/76652] host C: mkbootfs <= system/core/cpio/mkbootfs.c
FAILED: out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/mkbootfs.o 
/bin/bash -c "PWD=/proc/self/cwd  prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-copperhead/bin/clang     -I system/core/cpio -I out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates -I out/host/linux-x86/gen/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include_jni \$(cat out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/import_includes)  -I system/core/include -I system/media/audio/include -I hardware/libhardware/include -I hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -I hardware/ril/include -I libnativehelper/include -I frameworks/native/include -I frameworks/native/opengl/include -I frameworks/av/include  -c  -Wa,--noexecstack -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS --gcc-toolchain=prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8 --sysroot prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/sysroot -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -no-canonical-prefixes -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd= -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-expansion-to-defined -Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant -fdebug-prefix-map=\$PWD/=   -target x86_64-linux-gnu -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/x86_64-linux/bin   -std=gnu99  -Werror -fPIE -D_USING_LIBCXX -DANDROID_STRICT   -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=return-type -Wno-tautological-constant-compare -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-enum-compare -Wno-enum-compare-switch -MD -MF out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/mkbootfs.d -o out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/mkbootfs.o system/core/cpio/mkbootfs.c"
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-copperhead/bin/clang.real: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[  0% 19/76652] Check module type: out/target/produc...ic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libm_intermediates/link_type
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
18:41:30 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/make/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
```

It seems to me that something changed about the mkbootfs that is not updated in the make script, or maybe I made something wrong preparing the image...

The tutorial Im followwing is this:

[https://copperhead.co/android/docs/building](http://%20https://copperhead.co/android/docs/building)

A similar problem I found in discussion in Xda-developers forum, but cannot understand how to fix it:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-2/help/recipe-target-runsoongui-failed-t3782046

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems CopperheadOS is deprecated and doesn`t have compatibility with the recent version of Android bootfs..